# react router work on reload, but not when clicking on a link of navbar

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, create-react-app, mern

In my react app when i start it and try to click on different links on Navbar, page doesn't change at all as expected, only url seen to be changed. but when i reload the page then new page get loaded.

this is react-router-dom version 6

This is my App.js file

```
import './App.css';

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import News from './components/News';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom"

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Router> 
        <Navbar/>
        <div className='container my-3'>  
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" element={<News pageSize={5} country="in" category="general"/>}></Route>
            <Route exact path="/business" element={<News pageSize={5} country="in" category="business"/>}></Route>
            <Route exact path="/entertainment" element={<News pageSize={5} country="in" category="entertainment"/>}></Route>
            <Route exact path="/health" element={<News pageSize={5} country="in" category="health"/>}></Route>
            <Route exact path="/science" element={<News pageSize={5} country="in" category="science"/>}></Route>
            <Route exact path="/sports" element={<News pageSize={5} country="in" category="sports"/>}></Route>
            <Route exact path="/technology" element={<News pageSize={5} country="in" category="technology"/>}></Route>
          </Routes>
        </div>
        </Router>
      </>  
    );
  }
}
```

and this is Navbar

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export class Navbar extends Component {

  render() { 
    return (
      <div>
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">NewsMonkey</a>
                    <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                        <li className="nav-item">
                        <a className="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item"><Link className="nav-link" to="/">General</Link></li>
                        <li className="nav-item"><Link className="nav-link" to="/business">Business</Link></li>
                        <li className="nav-item"><Link className="nav-link" to="/entertainment">Entertainment</Link></li>
                        <li className="nav-item"><Link className="nav-link" to="/health">Health</Link></li>
                        <li className="nav-item"><Link className="nav-link" to="/science">Science</Link></li>
                        <li className="nav-item"><Link className="nav-link" to="/sports">Sports</Link></li>
                        <li className="nav-item"><Link className="nav-link" to="/technology">Technology</Link></li>
                        
                    </ul>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </nav>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Navbar
```